# Quiz questions with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I create quiz app with angularjs and have some issues.
When I click "next" checked radio doesn`t reset

```
<div ng-repeat="answ in quiz.typical">
    <label ng-click="quiz.checkAnsw()">
    <input type="radio" name="answ{{quiz.qNum}}">                    
        {{answ.text}}                    
    </label>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dT79P/1/)
How reset checked radio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set values to the radio then bind them to a property via `ng-model`:

```
<div ng-repeat="answ in quiz.typical">
  <label ng-click="quiz.checkAnsw()">
    <input type="radio" name="answ{{quiz.qNum}}" ng-value="$index" ng-model="quiz.selectedAns" />
    {{answ.text}}
  </label>
</div>
```

and in the controller, reset the `quiz.selectedAns` to `undefined`:

```
this.changeQ = function(){
  this.qNum++;
  this.selectedAns = undefined;
};
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zug5y/